# (1/1) FatalErrorException Cannot declare class Bitcoin, because the name is already in use in easybitcoin.php line 4

Tags: php, laravel, rpc, bitcoind

i have 2 files both named the same `easybitcoin.php` & `Easybitcoin.php`

This is the Error it throws

> (1/1) FatalErrorException
>
> Cannot declare class Bitcoin, because the name is already in use in
>   easybitcoin.php line 4

Line 4 is

```
class Bitcoin {
```

If someone could point me in the right direction. Everytime i go to click Generate New Wallet Address. Laravel throws this error

```
<?php 

class Bitcoin {
    // Configuration options
    private $username = ;
    private $password;
    private $proto;
    private $host;
    private $port;
    private $url;
    private $CACertificate;
    // Information and debugging
    public $status;
    public $error;
    public $raw_response;
    public $response;
    private $id = 0;
    /**
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $password
     * @param string $host
     * @param int $port
     * @param string $proto
     * @param string $url
     */
    function __construct($username, $password, $host = 'localhost', $port = 8332, $url = null) {
        $this->username      = $username;
        $this->password      = $password;
        $this->host          = $host;
        $this->port          = $port;
        $this->url           = $url;
        // Set some defaults
        $this->proto         = 'http';
        $this->CACertificate = null;
    }
    /**
     * @param string|null $certificate
     */
    function setSSL($certificate = null) {
        $this->proto         = 'https'; // force HTTPS
        $this->CACertificate = $certificate;
    }
    function __call($method, $params) {
        $this->status       = null;
        $this->error        = null;
        $this->raw_response = null;
        $this->response     = null;
        // If no parameters are passed, this will be an empty array
        $params = array_values($params);
        // The ID should be unique for each call
        $this->id++;
        // Build the request, it's ok that params might have any empty array
        $request = json_encode(array(
            'method' => $method,
            'params' => $params,
            'id'     => $this->id
        ));
        // Build the cURL session
        $curl    = curl_init("{$this->proto}://{$this->host}:{$this->port}/{$this->url}");
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH       => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
            CURLOPT_USERPWD        => $this->username . ':' . $this->password,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array('Content-type: application/json'),
            CURLOPT_POST           => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $request
        );
        // This prevents users from getting the following warning when open_basedir is set:
        // Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when in safe_mode or an open_basedir is set
        if (ini_get('open_basedir')) {
            unset($options[CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION]);
        }
        if ($this->proto == 'https') {
            // If the CA Certificate was specified we change CURL to look for it
            if ($this->CACertificate != null) {
                $options[CURLOPT_CAINFO] = $this->CACertificate;
                $options[CURLOPT_CAPATH] = DIRNAME($this->CACertificate);
            }
            else {
                // If not we need to assume the SSL cannot be verified so we set this flag to FALSE to allow the connection
                $options[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = FALSE;
            }
        }
        curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
        // Execute the request and decode to an array
        $this->raw_response = curl_exec($curl);
        $this->response     = json_decode($this->raw_response, TRUE);
        // If the status is not 200, something is wrong
        $this->status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        // If there was no error, this will be an empty string
        $curl_error = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        if (!empty($curl_error)) {
            $this->error = $curl_error;
        }
        if ($this->response['error']) {
            // If bitcoind returned an error, put that in $this->error
            $this->error = $this->response['error']['message'];
        }
        elseif ($this->status != 200) {
            // If bitcoind didn't return a nice error message, we need to make our own
            switch ($this->status) {
                case 400:
                    $this->error = 'HTTP_BAD_REQUEST';
                    break;
                case 401:
                    $this->error = 'HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED';
                    break;
                case 403:
                    $this->error = 'HTTP_FORBIDDEN';
                    break;
                case 404:
                    $this->error = 'HTTP_NOT_FOUND';
                    break;
            }
        }
        if ($this->error) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        return $this->response['result'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do both files define the `Bitcoin` class? Please show the full error.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two classes with same name, or you are including the same class twice.
Assuming the problem is the first, you can assign a namespace to each file.
Then, if you need call the second class into the first, you can give it an alias and call it through this.

file1.php:

```
namespace App\Something;

class Bitcoin {
    public static doSomething(){}
}
```

file2.php:

```
namespace App\YouCoolPath;

use App\Something\Bitcoin as YourAlias;

class Bitcoin {
    public function __construct() {
        YourAlias::doSomething();
    }

}
```